# IF statement in Excel - How to give value to 2 or more cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have a IF statement in one of my cells, for example (this didn't work):

```
=IF(B6="A10VG 125/32",D4="2.67" & C6="125.0","N/A")
```

**Q:** How would I make `D4` hold the value "2.67" and the cell `C6` hold the value "125.0", `IF` `B6` is equal to "A10VG 125/32"

So if one cell holds a certain condition how can I give different values to a number of different cells?

Comment: Why not just make an IF statement in each of your cells (D4 and C6)?

Comment: @williamgearty I thought it would be more 'efficient' with one 'if' statement...

Comment: I don't think it is possible to set other cell values with simple functions. If you really want to be able to do this, you will need to utilize macros: http://superuser.com/questions/602216/how-do-you-write-an-excel-formula-that-will-paste-a-specific-value-in-a-differen

Comment: A formula cannot directly manipulate the contents of another cell. You will need one in D4 and C6 as suggested by William Gearty

Comment: I used vlookup instead..

Answer (score 0):

Excel functions exist to determine the value of the given cell only. Input in, output out. You will need a separate function for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Excel formulas in a cell can **NOT** change the values of other cells.

If you want to use formulas, then you will need to put the appropriate formula into the respective cells.

In this scenario, in D4 use the formula

```
=IF(B6="A10VG 125/32","2.67","N/A")
```

In C6 use the formula

```
=IF(B6="A10VG 125/32","125.0","N/A")
```